# Algolia voice-overlay-ios change titleListening

Tags: ios, swift, search, algolia, voice

I want to change "listening..." text of `inputScreen`:

`voiceOverlayController.settings.layout.inputScreen.titleListening = "Another text for listening..."`

but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add your code for changing the UI in the appropriate lifecycle of the ViewController. I have the following appear correctly when the code is under `viewDidAppear(:_)`:

```
voiceOverlayController.settings.layout.inputScreen.titleListening = "Voice-search is not enabled."
```